# How to save visual representation of the graph js.cytoscape

Tags: javascript, layout, graph, cytoscape.js

Please somebody help me.
I need to save visual layout (after nodes of graph was manipulated) and load this visual representation next time.

I tried to save position of each node, and write this positions in input json {data:{id..}, position{x=.y=}.
But new graph was draw incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of positions, where it is on screen and where it is on graph. Be sure to save and load the right one. It might not look the same on your screen if you have panned or zoomed the view port. But the graph relative positions should be able to be saved.